# How to diff a commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

Let's say if I do a `git log` and see one commit with ID `280c5af57b02c41edbf947a0eed31c72e2839123`

It seems that to see what changes are made in that commit, I can either do

```
git diff 280c5af57^ 280c5af57
```

or

```
git show 280c5af57
```

However, since I already set up `opendiff` as the diff tool (using the instruction on https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690), the first command above will show it using `opendiff`, while the second command will use the diff on the command line.

Instead of using a Bash alias or function, is there a way to tell `git` to diff it without typing or pasting in the commit ID twice?  (like `svn diff -c 321234`)

Comment: Does git diff 280c5af57b02c41edbf947a0eed31c72e2839123 not work for you?

Comment: @動靜能量 why don't you want to use a Bash or Git alias?

Comment: @Cupcake because if you tell me I can use `moremore foo.txt foo.txt` to show a file, I will ask, without using alias, can I just type in `foo.txt` once

Answer (score 6):

`git diff` defaults to comparing against the working tree and/or index.  The command that's built to compare trees straight out of the repo is `git diff-tree`.  Try:

```
git diff-tree --ext-diff -p 280c5af
```

Comment: Note that `git diff-tree` and `git show` both do something different (and generally sensible) with merge commits (controllable with `-c`, `--cc`, and `-m`).  With plain `git diff`, you identify two specific trees, so the special actions for combined diffs are not applicable.

Comment: aha, but `opendiff` won't be used to diff it... only the command line diff

Comment: Ah. I see the docs say you have to turn that on explicitly.  I don't use them, this should do the trick now if I'm reading it right.

Comment: `git diff-tree --ext-diff -p 280c5af` will still only use the command line diff (not opendiff)

Comment: Try `export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=/path/to/your/diff` first. The docs say it consults that, it may be nobody taught it to also consult the config yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to your `gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    changes = !sh -c 'git diff "$0^" "$0"'
```

Now you can run

```
git changes 280c5af57b02c41edbf947a0eed31c72e2839123
```

and you only have to specify the SHA (or whatever) once.

(This answer does feel kind of heavy. Does anyone have a solution that doesn’t jump through the `!sh -c` hoop?)

Comment: isn't this almost the same as using a bash alias?

Comment: @動靜能量 In some sense, yes. But this has the advantage that you’re typing `git <something> <sha>`, just like any other Git subcommand.